# Angular2 TypeScript 2 methods, one variable not returning value

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service called `DropdownProjectService` with an object `selectedProjects: Object = new Array();`

I have 2 functions, one to add data to `selectedProjects` and one to retreive the data.

dropdown-projects.service.ts

```
export class DropdownProjectService {

    selectedProjects: Object = new Array();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.selectedProjects = new Array();
    }

    addProjects(project: Project){
        this.selectedProjects.push(project);
        console.log('this.selectedProjects in DropdownProjectService.addProjects()');
        console.log(this.selectedProjects);
    }

    getProjects(){
        console.log('this.selectedProjects in DropdownProjectService.getProjects()');
        console.log(this.selectedProjects);
        return this.selectedProjects;
    }
}
```

I have logged the variable in both functions. In the `addProjects` function `selectedProjects` shows objects, but in the `getProjects()` method, `selectedProjects` is and remains an empty array. I wonder why this is and what can be done about that. If I need to post more code, I will but for now I don't know which code to show.

app.ts:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'es6-shim';
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation, View, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChange, ElementRef, FormBuilder, provide, bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { DebugElementViewListener } from 'angular2/platform/common_dom';
import {ActualsComponent} from './actuals/actual.component';
import {ActualsFormComponent} from './forms/actuals-form.component';
import {ActualsService} from './actuals/actual.service';
import {HelloWorldComponent} from './hello-world/hello-world.component';
import {HelloWorldService} from './hello-world/hello-world.service';
import {UsersFormComponent} from './users/users-form.component';
import {UserService} from './users/user.service';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {LoginService} from './login/login.service';
import {DropdownProjectService} from './elements/dropdown/dropdown-projects.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app/templates/main.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ActualsComponent, HelloWorldComponent, UsersFormComponent, LoginComponent], 
    injectables: [ActualsService, HelloWorldService, UserService, LoginService]
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent, as: 'Login' },
    { path: '/', redirectTo: ['/Login'] },
    { path: '/actuals', component: ActualsComponent, as: 'Actuals'},
    { path: '/helloworld', component: HelloWorldComponent, as: 'HelloWorld'},
    { path: '/users', component: UsersFormComponent, as: 'Users' },
])

export class AppComponent { }

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, DropdownProjectService,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
]);
```

dropdown-projects.ts

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, RouteParams, Router, RouterOutlet, RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';
        import {FORM_PROVIDERS, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, NgClass, NgIf, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
        import {Component, Inject, Input, OnInit, OnChanges} from 'angular2/core';
        import {Http, Headers, ContentHeaders, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

        import {ActualsComponent } from '../actuals/actual.component';
        import {ProjectService} from '../../projects/project.service';
        import {LoginService} from '../../login/login.service';
        import {SearchPipe} from '../custom-pipes/search-pipe';
        import {DropdownProjectService} from './dropdown-projects.service';

        @Component({
            selector: 'dropdown-projects',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/elements/dropdown-projects.html',
            providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ProjectService, LoginService],
            directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink, CORE_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet],
            pipes: [SearchPipe]
        })

        export class DropDownProjects implements OnInit, OnChanges{
            projectdata: Object;

            public showMenu: boolean;

            constructor(public dropdownProjectService:DropdownProjectService,public loginService: LoginService, private http: Http,  params: RouteParams) {

                this.showMenu = false;
                loginService.authenticate("user", "pwd");
                this.projectdata = loginService.data;
            }

            addProject(project: Project) {
                this.dropdownProjectService.addProjects(project);
                console.log('project added');
            }
        }
```

These components and services are a mess. I intend to clean up everything that is not used. I don't like sloppy code but still cannot help creating it...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the elements that call your service don't share the same instance of your `DropdownProjectService` service. I mean if you call the service method from two different components and each component defines the service in its `providers` attribute, a dedicated service instance will be used by component. So you won't be able to share service properties between them...

Do you define the corresponding provider when bootstrapping your Angular2 application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ DropdownProjectService ]);
```

Comment: I used this service in 2 components. If I read you correct then I should bootstrap the service. Is it needed to inject the service in both components or is this taken care of in the bootstrap?

Comment: Don't change the way you inject the service in your components. Just remove this provider from the `providers` attributes of your components and add this provider within the second parameter when calling the `bootstrap` function...

Comment: I think I did everything you said and still the second function logs the selectedProject undefined.

Comment: Could you add in your question, the code of components calling the service and the way you bootstrap your application? Thanks!

Comment: "the second function logs the selectedProject undefined" -- check to make sure you don't have a typo.  You should not get `undefined`.  I.e., do you have `this.selectedProject` instead of `this.selectedProjects`, or did you forget `this.`?  If you can copy your code into a Plunker, that would help us (more like Thierry) debug it.